# Final self class for generics, in method signature, in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, reflection

I have a `BaseObject` model that defines common behaviour I want to share across all my data entities. It has a method like this:

```
class BaseObject {
    static func fetch(block: ((Results<BaseObject>) -> Void)) {
        // networking code here
    }
}
```

Naturally, I need the signature of this method be dynamic enough so that a model of class `Products`

```
class Products: BaseObject { //...
```

yields a `Results<Product>` list instead of `Results<BaseObject>`. I don't want to re-implement the `fetch` method in every subclass, because, save for the exact final subclass name used in the body and in the signature, it would be identical.

I cannot use `Self`:

[image: Xcode error]

Do I have any options at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now do this as of Swift 2.0 as it allows default implementations of methods in protocols.  To do so, you would make your base class a protocol, and use Self, as you tried in your example.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521

#### Edit:

This compiles in Swift 2.0 / Xcode 7.0 Beta:

```
class Results<T> {

}

protocol BaseObject {
    static func fetch(block: ((Results<Self>) -> Void))
}

extension BaseObject {
    static func fetch(block: ((Results<Self>) -> Void)) {
    // networking code here
    }
}
```

This feature is only available in Swift 2.0, to my knowledge, there is no solution in Swift 1.2 or previous.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I also thought of protocol extensions mentioned in the WWDC videos when I ran into this problem. However, I cannot yet port this project to Swift 2, because of a third party library dependency, so I'm hoping for a Swift 1.2 compatible solution.

Comment: I don't think there is any solution in 1.2 or earlier, but I posted sample code for 2.0.